# signTransaction is not a function?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

I want to test web3.js functionality, then I connect to Ganache, when I run the program web3.eth.getAccounts works properly, but web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction went wrong. I have no idea to solve it.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));

web3.eth.getAccounts(
    function (error, result){ 
    if(!error){
      console.log(result);
    } else{
      console.log(error);
    }
});

web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
        to: '0x93......',
        value: '1000000000000000000',
        gas: 2000000,
    },'19ec......', function (error, result){ 
        if(!error){
          console.log(result);
        } else{
          console.log(error);
        }
});
```

It returns

```
TypeError: web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\BC\coursetro-eth\test_web3.js:302:19)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11[39m
```

When I try another web3.eth.accounts, like web3.eth.accounts.hashMessage, it also returns the same problem.

```
web3.eth.accounts.hashMessage("Hello World", function (error, result){ 
    if(!error){
      console.log(result);
    } else{
      console.log(error);
    }
});

TypeError: web3.eth.accounts.hashMessage is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\BC\coursetro-eth\test_web3.js:315:19)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11[39m
```

This is the web3 version that I installed

```
"dependencies": {
     "web3": "^0.20.7"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get these errors, because you're using too old `web3.js` version. Recording to [this documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/web3js/downloads/pdf/v1.2.0/) `web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction` is part of `web3.js 1.0.0`. So just upgrade from 0.20.x to 1.0.x.

Comment: After I upgrade the web3 version, the problem has solved. Thank you.

Comment: @lamigo6666 Great, please accept the answer with the green check, so others having the same issue can use the same solution.